# How to get PREG_POSITION in XAMPP MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, xampp

I need to be able to extract the position of the first character of a code that will always be different, but will always match a pattern. I can flag that a field contains this code, but I need to know where it starts.

I've tried searching on how I can install that in my Portable XAMPP installation, but cannot find any instructions anywhere.  Can someone point me in the right direction please.

NOTE: github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme suggests you can install PREG as a UDF, but I'm at a loss as to how to.

Comment: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme suggests you can, but I'm at a loss as to how to install the function.

Comment: @Strawberry Slightly off-topic but one should not need to use regex in mysql. It's a clear sign that there is something wrong in the design. As such, I suggest to change that very design/structure if possible. I also recommend this book: [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557), it shows you some problems, the possible solutions and some exceptions to the rule. A great read.

Comment: @HamZa Not sure why that's directed at me, but OK. Anyway, I don't know whether it's appropriate to do genetic sequencing analysis, say, in MySQL, but if you did want to try, it seems that preg_match might be useful for that

Comment: @Strawberry Oops, wrong ping.

Comment: @Strawberry the database is used to store daily snapshots of an export from the master CRM Database. That is not under my control. The pattern matching *IS* required in this instance.  I appreciate your comments and it does sound like an interesting read, but is not relevant at this time.

Comment: @aSystemOverload not my recommendation